# How to implement a self initialising setter in c#

Tags: c#, properties, set, accessor

I want to use information hiding with a set accessor of a property. So I want to trigger the set accessor without putting any value in it. In the set acessor is the initialisation of the value, like this :

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     load short ref controls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reset">(re)set cached list</param>
    public List<ShortRef_Control> ShortRefControls
    {
        // (re)set cached list
        set
        {
            tableDictionary["refcontrols"] = 
              (from src in dataContext.ShortRef_Controls select src).ToList();
        }

        // return cached list
        get
        {
            return tableDictionary.Get<List<ShortRef_Control>>("refcontrols");
        }
    }
```

**Question**: Why I want to do this?
**Answer**: Two reasons: **1.** I also want to reset this, I use a cached list of a table with rows from database. When this table is updated, then I want to refresh the cached list. I don't want to use difficult readable setters for this and so want to hide the setter initialisation. **2.** I use key names, typing errors are then possible, keep those names together is a great solution.
**What works?** Possible not so great solution :
`ShortRefControls = null`

**Is the C# language missing something?** Or am I (mis)using properties this way. `ShortRefControls = null` works but If another collegue of mine is maintaining this code he could get the impression ShortRefControls value is set to null.

The best solution I can come up with is to don't use properties for this and Use a separate GetShortRefControls() and SetShortRefControls() function.

**UPDATE**: I (ahum...my collegue ;-) came up with this :

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     load short ref controls
    /// </summary>
    private void SetShortRefControls() => ShortRefControls = (from src in dataContext.ShortRef_Controls select src).ToList();
```

This private function is used as the setter value. In some way its behaving like an alias or a wrapper for the setter. **Whats wrong with this?** Its an extra function that would not really be needed.

**C# version x?** Is it strange to think that `ShortRefControls =<` is initializing with no value, is a way to handle this in a future version of C#. The **=<** characters could be off course any characters, meaning self initialization. To let the setter behave like a setter should, the **=** says ShortRefControls should get a value, the **<** says it will be initialised by itself and not passed as value.

**UPDATE 2**: Well after further thinking I came up with this :

```
/// <summary>
///     load short ref controls
/// </summary>
/// <param name="set">(re)set content cached list</param>
public List<ShortRef_Control> ShortRefControlList(bool set = false)
{
    // set or reset cache
    if (set)
      tableDictionary["refcontrols"] = 
        (from src in dataContext.ShortRef_Controls select src).ToList();

    // always return content of cache
    return tableDictionary.Get<List<ShortRef_Control>>("refcontrols");
}
```

I postfixed the methodname with List so we know a list is referenced for clarity. This is not what I really want and not efficient either because it always returns the value so I see the above code as a workaround.

**What I tried and did not work :** ShortRefControls = SelfInitialising. This can be good solution. SelfInitialising is a variable with null value. This makes it clear what the meaning will be. Problem with this is, I have not only ShortRefControls in the tableDictionary but a lot more data with different types so that won't do the trick.

What I really want is : **a self initialising setter**

So is there a better alternative to handle this or a good advice to the Visual Studio team to extend the language?

**UPDATE 3**
We have a setter and getter. Extend the c# language with an initializer, in short the keyword "init". So we get set, get, init. What does init do? Its sets the default value what otherwise has to be done with set. So in my example the setter is not use but the initializer is.

Comment: The whole point of making a setter is, so that the value can be set by accessors of the property/code calling the setter. If you want a setter to be "self-initializing", it defeats the whole purpose of a setter. I don't see the motivation to "go and initialize a property" when a caller is trying to set it's value. If you want the property to have a default value, just either set it in the constructor or initialize it in the getter.

Comment: The problem is not to initialize, but how to reinitialize.

Comment: I agree with @Lennart, what you are trying to do violates the single responsibility principle, which (in this case, a property) is to provide access to a field to the outer world, not keeping itself "up-to-date" (maybe you can implement a custom collection with a `Refresh` (or something else) method and call it like `obj.ShortRefControls.Refresh()` when you need?)

Comment: Well I think my problem is solved with the init keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the language doesn't support syntax to initialize a setter.

In my opinion, the code you've shown doesn't reflect your design choices. That means you're looking for syntax that expresses your intent better.

In my opinion, the `ShortRefControls` should be a readonly property:

```cs
public List<ShortRef_Control> ShortRefControls
{
    // return cached list
    get
    {
        return tableDictionary.Get<List<ShortRef_Control>>("refcontrols");
    }
}
```

Side note: you can shorten this to the following:

```cs
public List<ShortRef_Control> ShortRefControls =>
    tableDictionary.Get<List<ShortRef_Control>>("refcontrols");
```

Next, on to updating the cache for the `tableDictionary`. That shouldn't be done in a property setter: The `value` argument is not used, so it's not *setting* the property, it's doing something else. Callers would be confused, because this code doesn't do what it appears to do:

```cs
someObject.ShortRefControls = null;
```

The `null` is ignored, but `ShortRefControls` is set to *some other value*. That would surprise most developers looking at the code.

The method `SetShortRefControls` does what you need to update the dictionary entry. The important question is *when* that should be invoked. From the code fragments, it's hard to say, but here are some possibilities:

1. As part of the `get` accessor for `ShortRefControls`. That would ensure that the dictionary is always up to date. But, it effectively makes holding the cached value unnecessary.
2. In response to some other method (or methods) that invalidates the cache. I can't tell what those would be from the snippet provided.
3. After some period of time. Again, without more context, I can't say what time period would be correct.

Comment: That why I asked if its possible to extend the c# language with a self initializing setter, so no value is needed. The setter has an internal field variable, its under the hood a set method. I want to set this variable. The design purpose is to keep it all together with minimal code, but keep it readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the cache in constructor and not use a setter. Then based on your predefined conditions (ShouldReload) getter may reload cache. You can make Reload method private/public depending on whether you want to give the users of this class ability to reload cache explicitly.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<ShortRef_Control>> tableDictionary;

    public TestClass()
    {
        ReloadCache();
    }

    public List<ShortRef_Control> ShortRefControls
    {
        get
        {
            if (ShouldReload())
            {
                ReloadCache();
            }
            return tableDictionary["refcontrols"];
        }
    }

    public void ReloadCache()
    {
        tableDictionary["refcontrols"] =
           (from src in dataContext.ShortRef_Controls select src).ToList();
    }

    private bool ShouldReload()
    {
        return tableDictionary["refcontrols"] == null || !tableDictionary["refcontrols"].Any();
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is to much code is needed. The tableDictionary is not only used for ShortRefControls but for lets say 10 other tables related queries. I want to put the content of the tableDictionary in comboboxes. I also want to keep the code close/clean as possible. If you look at your sample code you see the key "refcontrols" in three separate code parts. I prefer to keep those in one Property getter & setter combo. For now the C# language does not support the situation of a self-initialising setter but may be if enough people vote for it will come :-)

Comment: If its used elsewhere then you can move reload functionality outside this class (make the dictionary static) and put in a helper class, so that it will be reloaded in a single point, whoever use this cache will reference the same dictionary. Setters are triggered when you set a property, your "self initializing setter" is somehow ambiguous. If you want to trigger loading when accessing this property first time (lazy loading) or conditionally then you need to use getter as shown in above code sample. Using setter for this purpose is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

How about expanding on ozanmut's solution and using an indexer to specify the table names?

This would retain ozanmut's clean pattern and it should also address your concerns with handling multiple tables:

```
    public class Tables
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, List<ShortRef_Control>> tableDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<ShortRef_Control>>();

        public List<ShortRef_Control> this[string tableName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (ShouldReload(tableName))
                    Reload(tableName);

                return tableDictionary[tableName];
            }
        }

        public void Reload()
        {
            foreach (var tableName in tableDictionary.Keys)
                Reload(tableName);
        }

        private void Reload(string tableName)
        {
            // implement table-specific loading logic here:
            switch (tableName)
            {
                case "refcontrols":
                {
                    tableDictionary[tableName] = (from src in dataContext.ShortRef_Controls select src).ToList();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"invalid table name: {tableName}");
                }
            }

            // note: in the real world I wouldn't use a switch statement to implement the logic, but this is just to 
            // illustrate the general concept
        }

        private bool ShouldReload(string tableName)
        {
            return tableDictionary[tableName] == null || !tableDictionary[tableName].Any();
        }
    }


    public class TestClass
    {
        private readonly Tables tables = new Tables();

        public TestClass()
        {
            tables.Reload();
        }

        // this indexer will allow you to access your various tables from outside this class by specifying the table name
        public List<ShortRef_Control> this[string name]
        {
            get { return tables[name]; }
        }

        // if you need your table names hard-coded, you can create separate properties for each one:
        public List<ShortRef_Control> RefControlsTable { get { return this["refcontrols"]; }}

        // here's a few examples of how the tables would be accessed or used

        public void UseTableRefControl()
        {
            UseTableRefControl(DoSomethingWithRecord);
        }

        public void UseTableRefControl(Action<ShortRef_Control> action)
        {
            TakeActionOnTable("refcontrols", DoSomethingWithRecord);
        }

        public void TakeActionOnTable(string tableName, Action<ShortRef_Control> action)
        {
            foreach (var row in tables[tableName])
                action(row);
        }

        private static void DoSomethingWithRecord(ShortRef_Control row)
        {
            // do something with the row here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The final solution I came up with hiding the `query` is to use one `method` and no `get/setters`. So that will be: `GetShortRefControls(true)`. When the parameter is `true` the `List` is (re)initialized. When the parameter is `false` the cached list is returned. You could make the parameter `optional`. So when its not given the `cached` list is always returned.